# How to bold partial text in a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, angular, string

I am trying to bold some words in a string, for example, I want the name variable to be bold. In my Angular component, my code is like this:

```
const name = 'Mike';
const message = `My name is ${name}.`
```

And I'm adding < b > tag to the string:

```
const message = `My name is <b>${name}</b>.`
```

But in my angular template, as I'm passing the message along, it did not bold the string. Instead, it shows 'My name is < b >Mike< /b >.' in UI.

```
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

I tried to encode the bracket but id didn't work; Are there any way that I can make it partial bold?

Comment: ##here is another page for you to look at.##
======= [They give the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010536/how-to-make-specific-part-of-a-string-bold-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably need to use innerHTML:

```
<div [innerHtml]="message"></div>
```

You can check [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation) for more information