# How to make text bold in string literal in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular8

Hi i am working on Angular application. I want to make some part of the text to bold so how to do it in string literal.

Here is the code in .ts class:

```
   if (res.status== "200") {
    this.colortext = `${res.colorofthebus} color is the best of ${res.othercolor}`;
  }
```

Here is the .html:

```
{{colortext}}
```

How can i make `res.colorofthebus` to bold while other to normal font.

TIA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make specific part of a string bold in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010536/how-to-make-specific-part-of-a-string-bold-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use innerHTML. Refer to [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-targets).

```
if (res.status== "200") {
    this.colortext = `<b>${res.colorofthebus}</b> color is the best of ${res.othercolor}`;
  }

...

<div [innerHTML]="colortext"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use the innerHtml of angular, like this:

.ts

```
this.colortext = `<strong>${res.colorofthebus}</strong> color is the best of ${res.othercolor}`;
```

.html

```
<span [innerHTML]="colortext"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<b>{{colortext?.colorofthebus}}</b> color is the best of {{colortext?.othercolor}}
```

.ts

this.colortext = res